# Simple way to create display a few dozen icons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview, android-orientation

In my app, I want to have some activities that display a series of small images, I'm aiming for 3 per row in portrait and 5 in landscape, but I'm not rigid about those numbers.

The first problem is, I can't figure out a layout, or a configuration of a layout that will allow me to achieve this effect properly. I've tried TableLayout, FrameLayout and RelativeLayouts, but none of them make my images look nicely arranged in both orientations.

In this case the images are flags. I've tried creating 9 Patches out of the ones with symbols in the middle which I don't want to be distorted. Android Studio doesn't pick up that they are `.9` files. But that is a separate issue.

```
     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/iceland"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>
```

I made a mockup of what I'm trying to achieve. I'd really really appreciate any tips you guys can offer. Thanks!

[image: Flag App 1]

[image: Flag App 2]

Comment: Have you tried `GridView`?

Comment: Like @kcoppock said, try a `GridView`, and change the column count when in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

taken from [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) should deliver an example, that could be useful to you.